# IUniswapV2Router02.swapExactTokensForTokens fails inside smart contract

Tags: solidity

I am trying to swap weth token to dai token (both ERC20) by uniswap router contract:

I tried following two approaches:

**1. use truffle console to manipulate weth/dai/router contract**. This method working fine. see detail below:

```
// Dai.sol
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;


contract Dai {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns(uint) {}
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256){}
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool){}
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256){}
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool){}
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool){}
}
```

```
// Weth.sol
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract Weth {
    function deposit() public payable {}
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external {}
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns(uint) {}
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns(uint) {}
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool){}
}
```

```
// Router.sol

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract Router {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts){}
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts){}
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] memory path)public view virtual returns (uint[] memory amounts) {}
}
```

There are the step by step commands line on truffle console:

```
truffle(kovan)> dai = await Dai.at("0x4f96fe3b7a6cf9725f59d353f723c1bdb64ca6aa")
truffle(kovan)> weth = await Weth.at("0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c")
truffle(kovan)> router =await Router.at("0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D")

truffle(kovan)> amountIn = await router.getAmountsIn(web3.utils.toWei("1"), [weth.address, dai.address])
truffle(kovan)> amountIn = amountIn[0]
truffle(kovan)> amountOut = web3.utils.toWei("1")
truffle(kovan)> weth.approve(router.address, amountIn)
truffle(kovan)> time = Math.floor((Date.now()/1000)) + 60*120
truffle(kovan)> router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOut, [weth.address, dai.address], accounts[0], time)
```

In this case, the transaction of swapExactTokensForTokens has been successfully gone through
(https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x11e51ad94d90ec9b2182768bcea87ad5a15d5cf83a91a02d52f2990cbaed5c61)

2. **import IUniswapV2Router02.sol from uniswapv2 and manipulate router.swapExactTokensForTokens in my contract.**

```
// SwapToken.sol
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract SwapTokens {
    
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
    
    event test (uint timestamp, uint amountIn, uint amountOut, address[] path, uint allowance, address sender);
    
    function swapper(address token1, address token2) public  {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token1;
        path[1] = token2;
        uint amountOut = 1 ether;
        uint amountIn = uniRouter.getAmountsIn(
            amountOut,
            path
        )[0];
                
        IERC20(token1).approve(address(uniRouter), amountIn);
        
        uint allowed = IERC20(token1).allowance(msg.sender, address(uniRouter));        
        
        emit test(now+90, amountIn, amountOut, path, allowed, msg.sender);

        uniRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amountIn, 
            amountOut,
            path, 
            msg.sender, 
            now + 120
        );
    }
}
```

Then I run the swapper function as below:

```
sw = await SwapTokens.deployed()
sw.swapper(weth.address, dai.address)
```

And the transaction fails with Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
(https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x3324fd65004e001163b665b79583f894e17854bc3371b89f39d472504cb4b46a)

These two approches seem both the same for me.
I do not know which part I have done mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it seems you're sending swapExactTokensForTokens with an 'amountOutMin' above 'amountIn', which is impossible.

See above the function prototype of swapExactTokensForTokens :

```
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
 uint amountIn,
  uint amountOutMin,
  address[] calldata path,
  address to,
  uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

amountOutMin must be smaller than amountIn, due to the slippage. You can find an example here :

JS Script :

```
  const amountIn = web3.utils.toWei("1");
  const amountsOut = await uniswapv2router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [WETH, SDT]);         
  const amountOutMin = amountsOut[1].mul(web3.utils.toBN(100 - SLIPPAGE_MAX)).div(web3.utils.toBN(100));
  const txSwap = await swapRouter.swapTokens([WETH, SDT], amountIn, amountOutMin, account);
```

Contract :

```
IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should approve tokens to your contract before call swapper function and need to transferFrom token from msg.sender to your contract.

```
uniRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn, 
        amountOut,
        path, 
        msg.sender, 
        now + 120
    );
```

This code doesn't bring tokens from msg.sender to router. This means swap token in your contract by uniRouter and send result token to msg.sender.